# How do I apply a transparent shader effect to a raw image in Unity?

Tags: image, unity-game-engine

I am trying to put an image over another. So I need the above image to be transparent to show the below image through above image.

I imported the image as asset and then created a raw image with that.

I tried to apply transparent layer mask (Select `layer` then `layer --> layer mask --> from transparency`) in Photoshop and then imported asset but that won't work.

Comment: You probably will ned a shader with two image sources, and a fade value. If the final picture should not recive any lightung the shader will be very simple.